# TabBar on bottom of app with Column

Tags: flutter, tabbar, appbar

I am trying to put the TabBar on the bottom of the app.

It worked so far, yet I can't get the pages to work (TabBarView). It just looks black and unresponsive. The TabBar is unresponsive too. Have I taken the wrong approach?

Currently, it looks like that:

[image]

And the code looks like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(Bookkeeper());

class Bookkeeper extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: DefaultTabController(
            length: 4,

            child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    verticalDirection: VerticalDirection.up,
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                        AppBar(
                            backgroundColor: Color(0xFF3F5AA6),
                            title: Container(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
                                child: menu(),
                            ),
                        ),

                    TabBarView(
                        children: [
                            Icon(Icons.directions_car),
                            Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
                            Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
                            Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
                        ],
                    ),
                ],
            ),
        ),
    );
}

Widget menu() {
        return TabBar(
            tabs: [
                Tab(
                    child: Container(
                        height: 45.0,
                        child: Column(
                            children:
                            [
                                Icon(Icons.euro_symbol),
                                Text(
                                    "Transactions",
                                    style: new TextStyle(
                                        height: 1.5,
                                        fontSize: 9.8,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                    ),
                                ),
                            ],
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
                Tab(
                    child: Container(
                        height: 45.0,
                        child: Column(
                            children:
                            [
                                Icon(Icons.assignment),
                                Text(
                                    "Bills",
                                    style: new TextStyle(
                                        height: 1.5,
                                        fontSize: 9.5,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                    ),
                                ),
                            ],
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
                Tab(
                    child: Container(
                        height: 45.0,
                        child: Column(
                            children:
                            [
                                Icon(Icons.account_balance_wallet),
                                Text(
                                    "Balance",
                                    style: new TextStyle(
                                        height: 1.5,
                                        fontSize: 9.5,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                    ),
                                ),
                            ],
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
                Tab(
                    child: Container(
                        height: 45.0,
                        child: Column(
                            children:
                            [
                                Icon(Icons.settings),
                                Text(
                                    "Options",
                                    style: new TextStyle(
                                        height: 1.5,
                                        fontSize: 9.5,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                    ),
                                ),
                            ],
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ],
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you use Container inside Tab,  tab has icon and text properties

Comment: Hey that is bad coding style, just ignore it. The main purpose is getting the tabbar to the bottom. I managed to do that but now TabBarView isn't working.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use `bottomNavigationBar` to position the `Tabs` at the bottom of the screen

```
  class Bookkeeper extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return MaterialApp(
        home: DefaultTabController(
          length: 4,
          child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              backgroundColor: Color(0xFF3F5AA6),
              title: Text("Title text"),
            ),
            bottomNavigationBar: menu(),
            body: TabBarView(
              children: [
                Container(child: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
                Container(child: Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
                Container(child: Icon(Icons.directions_bike)),
                Container(child: Icon(Icons.directions_bike)),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

     Widget menu() {
return Container(
  color: Color(0xFF3F5AA6),
  child: TabBar(
    labelColor: Colors.white,
    unselectedLabelColor: Colors.white70,
    indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
    indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
    indicatorColor: Colors.blue,
    tabs: [
      Tab(
        text: "Transactions",
        icon: Icon(Icons.euro_symbol),
      ),
      Tab(
        text: "Bills",
        icon: Icon(Icons.assignment),
      ),
      Tab(
        text: "Balance",
        icon: Icon(Icons.account_balance_wallet),
      ),
      Tab(
        text: "Options",
        icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

}
}

[image]

Comment: Hey, I want the AppBar on the bottom like on my screenshot. That is how I tried it and it did not work. Actually it did but the pages were unresponsive. Screenshot again: https://i.imgur.com/dTTcj2X.png - it should look like this.

Comment: Thank you but now the TabBar effects are gone.

Comment: what do you mean? could you put a screenshot?

Comment: I mean that the opacity / transparency of the other icons change when you change the page. This doesn't happen with your version anymore. Also the line under the selection doesn't have the same width. It's coming close though.

Comment: just change the properties bro, I updated my answer , check the menu() method

Comment: Thanks man, I gave you an upvote and correct answer. I will work up from there on. Sorry for the problems, I'm new to this Flutter thing.

Comment: @diegoveloper Great job, but I have one question.. if we use bottomnavigation bar will I be able to save the state in each tab... I am hearing there are issues w.r.t state?